# Android AMR-WB audio recording

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-2.3-gingerbread, amr

I'm trying to make audio recording in such a way:

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();    
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);  
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
mRecorder.prepare();
mRecorder.start();
...
```

On Samsung Galaxy SII (4.0.4) and Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.2) it works perfectly. But on SonyEricsson Xperia Pro (4.0.4) it creates not valid 3gp file.
On Android 2.3.* it make record with wrong speed (effect, like normal recording accelerated into 3-4 times).
As I understand I can't use `setAudioEncodingBitRate` and`setAudioSamplingRate` methods with AMR (am I right, actually?).
Maybe someone knows about right MediaRecorder tunes (or workarounds) for AMR-WB or I make something in wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: You're welcome ;) It's been quite a while since I worked with any of the MSM8255-based products, and I wasn't involved at all in the ICS upgrade. I know that there's been patches for AMR-WB recording at the Codeaurora Forum on the Jellybean branch for MSM8960/APQ8064 not that long ago, but I can't say for sure if it's supposed to work on those older products. I might be able to check when I'm at work.

Comment: You'll make me a big favour - check it, please (:

Comment: I've tested doing an AMR-WB/3GP recording on an XPeria Arc (I don't have access to an XPeria Pro but they use the same platform) running Android 2.3.4 and didn't experience any problems. The recorded 3GP file seems to play back fine on the device. The settings I used were 16000 Hz sample rate, 1 channel, 8 buffers, buffer size 2048.

Comment: Thanks! Did you record with MediaRecorder? Probably not, because with it buffer size and buffer count can't be set. Describe in what way you tested it, please.

Comment: We have a test application for internal use. I didn't set the buffer size/count though, I'm just listing what the multimedia framework picked. All I did was select the 3GP container, AMR-WB encoder and 16 kHz sample rate.

Comment: Set sampling rate fixes speedy effect on 2.3 (but it kills main AMR feature - variable bit and sample rate, as I understand -> recording has relatively big size). On Xperia Pro there isn't this codec (in /etc/media_profiles.xml) ):

Thank you! It was very helpful.

Comment: AMR-WB always samples at 16 kHz. The bitrate can change dynamically between 9 different predefined rates depending on the network conditions when in a voice call. When doing a local recording the bitrate might never change.